# epoch time to datetime conversion python

Tags: python-3.x, epoch

I am using python 3.6.2 and trying to convert epoch to datetime by using the following,

```
creation_date=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(epoch)
```

I am getting the following error,

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

It failed for '1535539535018'.

Comment: `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime())` works perfectly fine for me. What epoch did you use? this will work for any number of seconds

Comment: It failed for '1535539535018'

Comment: @Onyambu, yup sure thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aught to ensure that your epoch time is in seconds:

```
 time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1535539535018/1000))
```